# What is the biggest known safe prime number?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, big-numbers

I am looking for the biggest known [safe prime number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime). Can someone provide some reference to what that number is and a proof that it is indeed a safe prime number?

Comment: From the link you posted youself: "As of October 2012, the largest known safe prime is $18543637900515 × 2^{2666668} − 1$"

Comment: @mrf Hmm, this is what I get for posting references from my old question without looking through them. Today I learned what a Sophie Germain prime is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$18543637900515 × 2^{666668} − 1$.

From the same link you had posted. And the proof, equate it to $2k+1$, and check whether $k$ is a prime.

If $k$ is a prime it is a Sophie Germain prime.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime

Answer (score 0):

As of October $2012$, the largest known safe prime is $18543637900515\cdot2^{666668}−1$. This is paired to the biggest [Sophie Germain prime number found](http://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=2) in April $2012$, which is $18543637900515\cdot2^{666667}-1$.